# jQuery menu (show - hide) sometimes needs 2 clicks

Tags: jquery, menu

I have a simple menu which on click shows sub menus
It's not working properly. sometimes it's fine, but most of the times especially after click in the body, menu will need 2 click to show sub.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47jL54m4/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[data-toggle]").click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).data("toggle");
    var X = $(selector).attr('id');
    if (X == 1) {
      $(selector).hide();
      $(selector).attr('id', '0');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(selector).show();
      $(selector).attr('id', '1');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

  //Mouse click on sub menu
  $(".dMenu").mouseup(function() {
    return false;
  });
  $(".dMenu").click(function() {
    return false;
  });
  //Document Click
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".dMenu").hide();
    $("div[data-toggle]").attr('id', '');
    $("div[data-toggle]").removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #1183D5;
  text-align: center;
}
#all {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
}
.menu {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #539CF4;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dMenu {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #CCCDEC;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="all">
    <div class="menu usrFirst" data-toggle=".firstMenu">menu1
      <div class="firstMenu dMenu">first</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu usrSecond" data-toggle=".secondMenu">menu2
      <div class="secondMenu dMenu">second</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu usrThird" data-toggle=".thirdMenu">menu3
      <div class="thirdMenu dMenu">third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>main page (click here to hide all sub-menus, then click on menus again)
</div>
```

---

Solution: instead of stopping propagation, I used this approach: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47jL54m4/10/)

Comment: Don't use the `id` attribute to store information, use `$(this).data()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close all the submenus by clicking on the document, you don't change the IDs of the submenus. You clear the IDs of the menu buttons, but they don't have IDs. `$("div[data-toggle]").attr('id', '')` should be `$(".dMenu").attr('id', '')`.

But using IDs as a flag this way is poor design. You're also creating duplicate IDs, but they're supposed to be unique. You should instead store it with `.data()`.

Another problem is that when you click on the menu button, that also sends the `mouseup` event to the document first. So that event handler is clearing all the `active` flags. The fix for this is to use a `click` handler there as well, and put `e.stopPropagation` in the click handler for the button so it prevents the click from bubbling up to the document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[data-toggle]").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var selector = $(this).data("toggle");
    var X = $(selector).data('active');
    if (X == 1) {
      $(selector).hide().data('active', 0);
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(selector).show().data('active', 1);
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });

  //Mouse click on sub menu
  $(".dMenu").mouseup(function() {
    return false;
  });
  $(".dMenu").click(function() {
    return false;
  });
  //Document Click
  $(document).click(function() {
    $(".dMenu").hide().data('active', 0);
    $("div[data-toggle]").removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #1183D5;
  text-align: center;
}
#all {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
}
.menu {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #539CF4;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dMenu {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #CCCDEC;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="all">
    <div class="menu usrFirst" data-toggle=".firstMenu">menu1
      <div class="firstMenu dMenu">first</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu usrSecond" data-toggle=".secondMenu">menu2
      <div class="secondMenu dMenu">second</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu usrThird" data-toggle=".thirdMenu">menu3
      <div class="thirdMenu dMenu">third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>main page (click here to hide all sub-menus, then click on menus again)
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for time and answer.
I re-edited my code thanks to you. since I was using .active class for another reason I changed the name. fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/47jL54m4/7/)
 now it works perfectly as I expected.
By the way I've read this about stopping propagation: [link](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/), and since I haven't had any problem without it so far, I didn't use it.

Thanks again :)